# How to kill all processes returned by pgrep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, kill

I need to kill a few Python processes. I can get a list of the process numbers using `pgrep python`, but how can I kill them all at once instead of killing one by one?

I'm looking for something like:

```
pgrep python | kill process_nos
```

Comment: `man killall`...

Comment: Besides possibly being a snide remark, "man killall" is not a correct answer.  How would killall work with a Python script launched using "python /foo.py"? How about if that python cron were launched from a cron which first invokes a wrapper script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try:

```
pgrep python | xargs kill
```

Comment: Why would you invoke THREE processes when one suffices?

Comment: For one process it would be 
kill $(pgrep name)

Comment: No, "kill $(pgrep name)" is still two processes and a shell. For one process, use `pkill` (as pointed out by @tink: https://superuser.com/a/742741)

Answer (score 27):

```
pkill python
```

Short and sweet, man pkill for details.

Comment: I found that `pkill python` does not always work, in cases where `kill PID` neither works. But `pgrep python | xargs kill -9` does. Can pkill do the equivalent?

Comment: Absolutely ... `pkill -9 <...>`

Comment: Bare in mind that it the process is stuck on e.g. broken I/O that, too, may not work. But in those cases only a reboot will ...

Answer (score 1):

@tink has the correct answer, but I wanted to add that you want to make sure you are using the correct format for your machine. If you are using a Linux machine, `pkill python` is correct, but if you are using a Mac terminal, you will want to use `pkill Python`. So the most correct answer would be this:

```
pkill <process_name>
```

where `<process_name>` is the case-sensitive name of the process to kill.

Note: I understand that the tags for this question were related to Ubuntu Linux, but I wanted to clarify this for anyone that has a different machine but had this exact question (like myself).

Answer (score 1):

If `pkill` is a bit too radical for your tastes and you prefer to select which entries of the `pgrep` listing you want to kill, you can have a look at `ezkill` <https://github.com/Kraymer/ezkill> that i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just run -

```
sudo kill -9 `pgrep python`
```